# How can I select a variable declared in a trigger (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, triggers

I've tryed to select @mess after the event (insert into impiegato...) and so also after the trigger execute, but the value of the variable is always null.
How can I fix the problem?

```
`DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER NomeNoCognome
 BEFORE INSERT ON impiegato FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
 IF new.Nome IN (SELECT Cognome FROM impiegato) OR new.Nome=new.Cognome
 THEN SET @mess='Non è possibile inserire un nome uguale ad un cognome della tabella!';
 SET new.Nome=null;
 END IF;
 END;
 //`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) instead.

> SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or to the client. Also, it provides control over the error's characteristics (error number, SQLSTATE value, message). Without SIGNAL, it is necessary to resort to workarounds such as deliberately referring to a nonexistent table to cause a routine to return an error.

There are plenty of examples in the linked manual page.